# How to expand person lookup field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, pnp-js-core

How do I select all the fields and expand a person lookup field using the pnp js library?

```
$pnp.sp.crossDomainWeb(addinweb, hostweb).lists.getByTitle("Sites").items.select('*').expand('Person Field').get().then(function (result) {
                //console.log(result);
                context.commit("setSites", result);
                resolve();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

you should know what exactly you looking for in Person/User so my guess is to try this 
Person/Title.

```
$pnp.sp.crossDomainWeb(addinweb,hostweb)
.lists.getByTitle("Sites")
.items.select('Person/Title')
.expand('Person')
.get()
.then(function (result) {
     //console.log(result);
     context.commit("setSites", result);
     resolve();
     });
```